# React: How to setState in child component from parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React and am attempting to set up a Bootstrap modal to show alert messages.

In my parent App.js file I have an error handler that sends a Modal.js component a prop that triggers the modal to show, eg:

On App.js:

```
function App() {

  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);

  // Some other handlers

  const alertModalHandler = (modalMessage) => {
    console.log(modalMessage);
    setModalShow(true);
  }

  return (
   // Other components.
  <AlertModal modalOpen={modalShow}/>
  )
}
```

And on Modal.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const AlertModal = (props) => {

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  if (props.modalOpen) {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <Modal show={isOpen}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>Hi</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>asdfasdf</Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default AlertModal;
```

However, this doesn't work. I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

If I change the Modal component to be a 'dumb' component and use the prop directly, eg:

```
 const AlertModal = (props) => {

  return (
    <Modal show={props.modalOpen}>
     <Modal.Header closeButton>Hi</Modal.Header>
     <Modal.Body>asdfasdf</Modal.Body>
     </Modal>
      );
    };
```

It does work, but I was wanting to change the show/hide state on the Modal.js component level as well, eg have something that handles modal close buttons in there.

I don't understand why is this breaking?

And does this mean I will have to handle the Modal close function at the parent App.js level?

**Edit - full app.js contents**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import AddUserForm from './components/addUserForm';
import UserList from './components/userList';
import AlertModal from './components/modal';

function App() {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);


  const addPersonHandler = (nameValue, ageValue) => {
    console.log(nameValue, ageValue);
  
    setUsers(prevUsers => {
      const updatedUsers = [...prevUsers];
      updatedUsers.unshift({ name: nameValue, age: ageValue });
      return updatedUsers;
    });
  };

  const alertModalHandler = (modalMessage) => {
    console.log(modalMessage);
    setModalShow(true);
  }

  let content = (
    <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>No users found. Maybe add one?</p>
  );

  if (users.length > 0) {
    content = (
      <UserList items={users} />
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <AddUserForm onAddPerson={addPersonHandler} fireAlertModal={alertModalHandler}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            {content}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <AlertModal modalOpen={modalShow}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you share full App.js code? It's hard to say where the porblem is if rest of code is not visible.

Comment: @KonradPrzydział I've added it above

Comment: Are you sure that you correct bind event handlers inside <AddUserForm />?

Comment: @KonradPrzydział yes - the console.log works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your modal.js

you should put

```
if (props.modalOpen) {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }
```

in  a useEffect.

```
React.useEffect(() => {if (props.modalOpen) {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }}, [props.modalOpen])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never call `setState` just like that. If you do it will run on every render and trigger another render, because you changed the state. You should put the `setModalShow` together with the if clause in a `useEffect`. E.g.:

```
useState(() => {
  if (modalOpen) {
      setIsOpen(true);
    }
}, [modalOpen])
```

Note that I also restructered `modalOpen` out of `props`. That way the `useEffect` will only run when `modalOpen` changes.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand the last part. How did you get modalOpen? What is it structured out of props?

Answer (score 0):

If you already send a state called **modalShow** to the **AlertModal** component there is no reason to use another state which does the same such as **isOpen**.

Whenever **modalShow** is changed, it causes a re-render of the **AlertModal** component since you changed it's state, then inside if the prop is true you set another state, causing another not needed re-render when you set **isOpen**. Then, on each re-render if props.showModal has not changed (and still is true) you trigger **setIsOpen** again and again.

If you want control over the modal open/close inside **AlertModal** I would do as follows:

```
<AlertModal modalOpen={modalShow} setModalOpen={setModalShow}/>
```

Pass the set function of the **showModal** state to the modal component, and there use it as you see fit. For example, in an onClick handler.

**modal.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const AlertModal = (props) => {

  const onClickHandler = () => {
       props.setModalOpen(prevState => !prevState)
  }

  return (
    <Modal show={props.modalOpen}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>Hi</Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>asdfasdf</Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default AlertModal;
```

Comment: Yes I thought so. But this would mean I would have to put the close button functions on app.js - ie seperate them from the modal.js component all together. This seems a bit odd. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: As I see it, you need the setModalOpen both for AddUserForm and AlertModal, both are children of App so this set function should probably be at App.js.

If you want a close button function, it can certainly stay inside AlertModel, inside of this close function you can use the setShowModal you received in props and set it to false.